# Simple regex - finding words including numbers but only on occasion

Tags: regex, numbers, symbols, words

I'm really bad at regex, I have:

```
    /(@[A-Za-z-]+)/
```

which finds words after the @ symbol in a textbox, however I need it to ignore email addresses, like:

```
    foo@things.com
```

however it finds @things

I also need it to include numbers, like:

```
    @He2foo
```

however it only finds the @He part.

Help is appreciated, and if you feel like explaining regex in simple terms, that'd be great :D

Comment: do `you@want` to match on `@want` here? or do you only want to pick `@separate` tokens?

Comment: Sorry didn't see this earlier, only separate tokens, not something@this.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/(?:^|(?<=\s))@([A-Za-z0-9]+)(?=[.?]?\s)/
```

`@This` (matched) regex `ignores@this` but matches on `@separate` tokens as well as tokens at the end of a sentence like `@this.` or `@this?` (without picking the `.` or the `?`) And yes `email@addresses.com` are ignored too.

The regex while matching on `@` also lets you quickly access what's after it (like `userid` in `@userid`) by picking up the regex `group(1)`. Check PHP documentation on how to work with regex groups.

Comment: Hi. This seems to work well, but it ignores the very first match, e.g.: http://puu.sh/2TYn0.png the first one is ignored because it's the start of the text.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add 0-9 to your regex, like so:

```
/(@[A-Za-z0-9-]+)/
```

Don't think any more explanation is needed since you've been able to come this far by yourself. `0-9` is just like `a-z` (though numeric ofcourse).

In order to ignore emailaddresses you will need to provide more specific requirements. You could try preceding `@` with `(^| )` which basically states that your value MUST be preceeded by either the start of the string (so nothing really, though at the start) or a space.

Extending this you can also use `($| )` on the end to require the value to be followed by the end of the string or a space (which means there's no period allowed, which is requirement for a valid emailaddress).

**Update**

```
$subject = "@a @b a@b a@ @b";
preg_match_all("/(^| )@[A-Za-z0-9-]+/", $subject, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Comment: `/(^| )@[A-Za-z0-9-]+/` try this instead (wrap it to prevent any mistakes). Also, make sure this approach still matches your requirements.

Comment: Sorry about that, hit enter before I had typed it. I tried the example I have there, and it worked pretty well except ignored the very first match (because there was nothing before it), about to try ^| now.

Comment: Yes the `$`-sign is the endmark of a string. Was my mistake in editing. The `^`-sign however is the startmark of a string. The `|`-sign is a so called `OR`-operator.

Comment: Updated my answer with an example, tested on [RegexPAL](http://regexpal.com). Yellow and blue values represent matches. Text left white doesn't match.

Comment: Note that I've left out the slashes, these are required in certain languages though are not part of the regex.

Comment: Sorry about this, I'm a little confused. I'm using regex in PHP so hence the slashes, but I'm going to write the whole line because I've done something wrong: 

`$userRegex = '/(^| @[A-Za-z0-9-]+)/';`